# C# listview groping разделители столбцов

Tags: c#, listview

При группировке в listview пропадают разделители столбцов, остаются только в заголовках. Гуглил, не помогло, понял только что их можно как то нарисовать, но как? Пару картинок приложу чтобы стало понятно чего я хочу добиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы стало вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Картинки из гугла

Comment: добавьте тег `winforms` если у вас этот тип проекта или что-то другое в противном случае.

Comment: Можете просто выставить свойство `GridLines = true`. При этом будут рисоваться разделители как столбцов, так и строк.

Comment: Не будут! При добавлении ListViewGroup все теряется. Иначе мне не пришлось бы изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем сам разобрался. 
Для начала добавляем после инициализации формы:

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
```

То есть указываем что сами будем рисовать сетку. Затем в свойствах listview жмякаем на события (значок молнии) и выбираем двойным кликом DrawColumnHeader и DrawSubItem. Добавляем следующий код:

```
    private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)//для отображения заголовков
    {
        var with1 = e.Graphics;
        with1.DrawLines(new Pen(SystemColors.ButtonFace), new Point[] { new Point(e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Top - 1), new Point(e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Top + e.Bounds.Height) });
        e.DrawText();
    }
    private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var with1 = e.Graphics;
        with1.DrawLines(new Pen(SystemColors.ButtonFace), new Point[] {/*new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top - 1),*/new Point(e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Top - 1), new Point(e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Top + e.Bounds.Height)/*,new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + e.Bounds.Height)*/});
        e.DrawText();
    }
```

Если нужна полная сетка разкомментируйте часть кода.
Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]